# How to store polygon2Dcollider points in an array or List

Tags: c#, list, unity-game-engine, polygon, collider

PolygonCollider2D can be composed of several paths (not only one) depending on the shape of the sprite it is applied on.

I am struggling to store all these coordinates, Vector2[], into one List.

Until now I was trying to access each path:

```
             for (int p=0; p<polygon1.pathCount; p++)
         {
            polygonpoints = new Vector2[polygon1.GetPath(p).Length]; 
            polygonpoints = polygon1.GetPath(p);
            polygons.Add(polygonpoints);           
         }
```

Where polygon1 is my PolygonCollider2D and polygonPoints is a Vector2[]. polygons is a declared List[polygon1.pathcount]

Why can't I add these Vector2[] in my List ? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I want to check with you before posting an answer. I believe your list just needs to be type of <Vector2[]>. e.g. `List<Vector2[]> polygons = new List<Vector2[]>();` then `polygons.Add(polygon1.points);`

Comment: You are right, it was a mistake from my side..! Thank you!

Comment: No problem, I will post the solution for acceptance. Cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your list just needs to be type of .

```
//Initialize the list with each element being a Vector2[] (Vec2 array)
List<Vector2[]> polygons = new List<Vector2[]>();

polygons.Add(polygon1.points);
```